# Cmd.Parameters.Refresh does not retrieve any parameters (anymore)

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, oledb

Since today, I run into the following error when trying to execute a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008 from VBA Excel.

> Run-time error '3265': Item cannot be found in the collection
>   corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

I've figured out that this error occurs because the `Cmd.Parameters.Refresh` command does not return any values. This becomes visible when printing the parameters count (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/count-property-ado?view=sql-server-2017).

Running the stored procedure in SQL Server with `EXEC` does not yield any problems. For completeness sake, I've added the SQL code below.

The weird thing is that exactly the same code in another (older) Excel file, does work neatly.

Below you can find both the VBA code and the SQL Alter/Create procedure code.

**VBA**

```vb
Option Explicit

Global Const Conn_999 As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=SERVER999; Initial Catalog=AA; Trusted_connection=yes"

Sub ReadAllFromdb()    
    ' -- Unprotect sheets  --        
    Sheets("Ind").Unprotect

    ' Get Id    
    Dim Id As Long
    Id = Cells(3, 2)

    ' -- Create connection --    
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command

    ' -- Connect to database (see Connection settings for details) --        
    Conn.Open Conn_999

    ' -- Bind ADODB connection to command  --    
    Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn

    ' -- Identify command type as stored procedure (all command types)  --    
    Cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    ' -- Set the name of the stored procedure (CommandText property) --    
    Cmd.CommandText = "OS.dbo.usp_GetId"

    ' -- Retrieve parameter information for the stored procedure  --    
    Cmd.Parameters.Refresh

    ' Retreive parameter count for debugging (return zero)    
    Debug.Print(Cmd.Parameters.Count) ' Prints 0

    Cmd.Parameters("@Id").Value = 888 ' ---------> ERROR <---------

    Set RS = Cmd.Execute(RecordsAffected:=RecordsAffected)    
    ...    
End Sub
```

**SQL Server**

```sql
USE [OS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_GetName]    Script Date: 5/6/2019 1:37:06 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetName]
    @Id INT
AS
    SELECT [Name]
    FROM [OS].[dbo].[All]
    WHERE Id = @Id

    RETURN
```

Any help to find the real source of this error would be more than welcome.

**EDIT (2019-05-09):**

Apparently, the error was caused by putting `OS.dbo.` in front of the stored procedure name. This meant, I had to create a new connection string and connection for each query on a different database, but it solved the issue.

Comment: This is possibly due to environment or network access. By different Excel files, are you saying .xls vs .xlsm on same machine or different machines? Try importing a `SELECT` resultset without parameters. Finally, try ODBC connection instead of OLEDB: `'Driver={SQL Server};Server=myserver;Database=mydb;UID=myuser; Trusted Connection=yes'`.

Comment: The two different Excel files are both '.xlsm', moreover they have exactly the same code (all on the same machine). But any new file with this code throws the same error. I've tried changing the connection, but unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Very unusual. Check the references in both (in VBA IDE on menu Tools\References) and compare ADO versions. Did simple query without parameters work?

Comment: I check the references, but there is no difference between the files.
Anyhow, after allowing Windows 10 to install updates, the error seems to have disappeared and both files are working fine again. Very odd behavior ...

Comment: Please refer to the answer for an additional solution.